# Unknown error while mounting an external USB device

Tags: boot, usb, mount, hard-drive

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on my laptop. I was copying some folders from an external USB device into my Windows virtual machine. The process stuck unexpectedly, the mouse was blocked as well as the clock time indicator, so I was only able to force the system shutdown through a button press.
When I reboot the system, I insert the USB device receiving the error:

**error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/eljamba/Seagate Expansion Drive: unknown error when mounting /dev/sda2**

Surprisingly the device is listed in the Mate file manager in the device section (Nautilus sidebar). Also when I give the command `lsusb`, I see my device as

*Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bc2:231a Seagate RSS LLC Expansion Portable*

Could someone provide a solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As reported in a previous [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236397/ubuntu-20-04-error-mounting-dev-sdb1-at-media), you should install or reinstall the **ntfs-3g** package, and then fix the issues of the **ntfs** partition.
So, first install/reinstall the package:

`sudo apt install --reinstall ntfs-3g`

and then fix the errors in */dev/sda1* partition

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1`